# Add Datalabel on the end of barchart (lollypop)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm totally new at using Python for Power BI (or anything really).
I would like to add the value of the bar/scatter at the end of the line. (the datalabel)

Also to have a version where I could have the label inside of the scatter bubble would be cool.

Anyone who could help out here ?

All help appreciated

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': dataset.Genre , 'values': dataset.Revenue})
val = list(dataset.SelectedGenre)

# Reorder it following the values:
ordered_df = df.sort_values(by='values')
my_range=range(1,len(df.index)+1)
 
# Create a color if the group is "B"
my_color=np.where(ordered_df ['group']== val, 'orange', 'skyblue')
my_size=np.where(ordered_df ['group']== val , 150, 150)

# The vertival plot is made using the hline function
# I load the seaborn library only to benefit the nice looking feature
import seaborn as sns
val = ordered_df['values']
plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=0, xmax=val, color=my_color, alpha=1 , linewidth=8)
plt.scatter(val, my_range, color=my_color, s=my_size, alpha=1)

# Add title and axis names
plt.yticks(my_range, ordered_df['group'])
plt.title("What about the B group?", loc='left')
plt.xlabel('Value of the variable')
plt.ylabel('Group')
plt.box(False) #Turn of Black bx around visual

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
x = dataset.Revenue
y = dataset.Genre
labels = dataset.Revenue
val = list(dataset.SelectedGenre)

# Create the figure and axes objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))
fig.suptitle('Example Of Labelled Scatterpoints')

my_color=np.where(y == val, 'orange', 'skyblue')
my_size=np.where( y == val , 2000, 2000)

# Plot the scatter points
ax.scatter(x, y,
           color= my_color,  # Color of the dots
           s=1000,         # Size of the dots
           alpha=1,     # Alpha of the dots
           linewidths=1)  # Size of edge around the dots

ax.hlines(y, xmin=0, xmax=x, color= my_color, alpha=1 , linewidth=8)

def human_format(num):
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000
    # add more suffixes if you need them
    return '%.0f%s' % (round(num), ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P'][magnitude])

# Add the participant names as text labels for each point

for x_pos, y_pos, label in zip(x, y, labels):
    ax.annotate(
                human_format(label),  # The label for this point
                xy=(x_pos, y_pos), # Position of the corresponding point
                xytext=(-8, 0),     # Offset text by 7 points to the right
                textcoords='offset points', # tell it to use offset points
                ha='left',         # Horizontally aligned to the left
                va='center',
                color = 'white')       # Vertical alignment is centered
plt.box(False) #Turn of Black bx around visual
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```